# Lost one of my questions

Tags: support

One of my questions appears to have been deleted. It was about how one can say a composer is better than another, and mentioned Eurovision, Taylor Swift, and (if I remember right) Mozart. It had an answer by (again if I remember right) [Richard](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/21766/richard), and it was closed for being opinion-based.

I am looking for that question since I can use the answer. I don't mind if it's not undeleted, but can I get a link to it?

Comment: If you haven't already, go to your profile's `questions` tab, scroll to the bottom, and try the `recently deleted questions` link. You may be able to access your deleted question there.

Comment: @Aaron it's not there unfortunately. It could have been deleted more than 60 days ago (it was certainly asked ~2? years ago).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still there. If you go into your profile, select questions, and ensure you are seeing all 10 questions (you have a link to *more* if you can only see a few)

The [question is here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/64716/104) in any case.

Comment: It might be that you can see ten questions only because you're a mod. I can only see seven (in fact, have I asked 10 questions?). Thanks for link, it's a useful one for me.